# Get 'Non-persisted field' value from PXSmartPanel

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am using a `PXSmartPanel` to display a dialog allowing a user to enter a string.  I would like to use a 'Non-persisted field', but that means (I think) that I would have to get the field value by calling the field on the Panel and extracting its value.

The text field's ID is `cstFieldSSN` and the non-persisted field's ID is `UsrSSN`

My method looks like this:
(I'm calling the dialog upon clicking a menu item)

```
// Initialize 'myPanel'
public PXFilter<PX.Objects.CR.Contact> myPanel;

// Make the 'Letters' menu available to 'Automation Steps'
public PXAction<PX.Objects.CR.Contact> letters;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Letters", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.Report)]
protected virtual IEnumerable Letters(PXAdapter adapter, string reportID)
{
    if (myPanel.AskExt(true) != WebDialogResult.OK) return;

    PXReportRequiredException ex = null;

    Contact contact = Base.Caches[typeof(Contact)].Current as Contact;

    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    parameters["ContactID"] = contact.ContactID.ToString();

    /** Here's the issue **/
    parameters["SSN"] = myPanel.Current.UsrSSN;

    throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, reportID, "");

    if (ex != null) throw ex;

    return adapter.Get();
}
```

I'm getting

> 'PX.Objects.CR.Contact' does not contain a definition for 'UsrSSN' and no extension method 'UsrSSN' accepting a first argument of type 'PX.Objects.CR.Contact' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Could someone help me out or point me to a resource?

Comment: you get the value from cache. the field from the DAC which is bound to a field on the smart panel. The DAC would come from the view which is bound to the panel. So something like MyView.Current.MyValue. Otherwise we might need more details from what code your added or tried to know more.

Comment: if you are trying to access an extension field you would do something like this... var myExt = myPanel.Current.GetExtension<ContactExt>() where ContactExt is the class with your extension UsrSSN field. Then you can use it like myExt.UsrSSN ... hope that helps

Comment: Ok. The errors went away, but I'm still not having success.  Where do I find the actual name of my class extension?  (I feel like that's a ridiculous question, but my field isn't being retrieved.)  When I 'inspect' my custom form field, it says it's part of Class 'Contact'.

Comment: I got it!  I didn't have 'CommitChanges' set.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Perfect. Don't forget to answer your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Brendan, my final code looks like this:

```
    // Initialize 'myPanel'
    public PXFilter<PX.Objects.CR.Contact> myPanel;

    // Make the 'Letters' menu available to 'Automation Steps'
    public PXAction<PX.Objects.CR.Contact> letters;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Letters", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.Report)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable Letters(PXAdapter adapter, string reportID)
    {
        // Launch the PXSmartPanel dialog and test result
        if (myPanel.AskExt(true) == WebDialogResult.OK)
        {
            PXReportRequiredException ex = null;

            Contact contact = Base.Caches[typeof(Contact)].Current as Contact;

            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //*** Get the extended class
            var myExt = myPanel.Current.GetExtension<ContactExt>();

            parameters["ContactID"] = contact.ContactID.ToString();

            //*** Get the extended class's custom field value
            parameters["SSN"] = myExt.UsrSSN;

            throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, reportID, "");

            if (ex != null) throw ex;
        }

        return adapter.Get();        
    }
```

But I also had to set the `CommitChanges` property on the text field to `True` so that the value would be pushed back to the cached Contact, allowing me to use it.